# How to replace View in Viewpager android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-view

I want to create E-book reader via viewpager,this book has 600 pages and it's bad way to creating 600 view because it has need a lot of memory.in each page i filling view with sqlite database

I think i must create 2 View and replace views for backward and forward pages.

I checked this link
http://developers-club.com/posts/132406/

My Code

```
Fragment khatm1 =new RootFragment();
Fragment khatm2 = new StaticFragment();

/* PagerAdapter class */
public class SlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public SlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        /*
         * IMPORTANT: This is the point. We create a RootFragment acting as
         * a container for other fragments
         */

        if  (currentItm > 604 || currentItm < 1){
            return null;
        }

        else {

            if (currentItm == 0)
                return new RootFragment();
            else
                return new StaticFragment();
        }


    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_ITEMS;
    }


    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(View container, int position) {
        if (position == getCount() - 1) {
            if (khatm1 == null) {
                return super.instantiateItem(container, position);
            } else {
                return khatm1;
            }
        } else {
            return super.instantiateItem(container, position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(View container, int position, Object object) {
        if (position == getCount() - 1) {

        } else {
            super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
        }
    }


}
```

How i can resolve my problem?

Comment: By default ViewPager only maintains 3 pages in memory, 1 to the left, 1 to the right of the current page, as the offScreenPageLimit is set to 1 by default. You can modify this value by calling viewpager.setOffScreenPageLimit(n) on your viewpager instance where n is the number of pages in memory both towards left and right of current item.

Comment: @nipun.birla . is it deprecated this command? viewpager.setOffScreenPageLimit(n)

Comment: No it's is not.

Comment: is it possible creating 2 page  and replacing each other for creating pages ?\